# Переход в другой класс по кнопке - JAVA

Tags: java, ооп, eclipse, jframe

Решил всё же тут задать вопрос, так как не могу найти ответ на свой вопрос в интернете.

В общем захотелось мне сделать кнопку, которая будет переводить пользователя в другой *JFrame* класс.

Грубо говоря на подобии  в *HTML*, переводящий на другую страницу этого же сайта.

В JAVA я грубо говоря новичок.

Буду благодарен всем, кто ответит на мой вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MyJFrame1 frame1 = new MyJFrame1(); // MyJFrame1 extends JFrame
...

frame1.setVisible(false); // скрываем JFrame №1
MyJFrame2 frame2 = new MyJFrame2(); // MyJFrame2 extends JFrame
frame2.setVisible(true); // показываем JFrame №2
...
```

Так же можно вместо `setVisible(false)`, можно попробовать использовать `dispose()`

*PS: мне кажется лучше не скрывать/показывать `JFrame`-ы, а использовать [JTabbedPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html)*

Правка:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("JFRAME2");
btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Acrom", Font.PLAIN, 22));
btnNewButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame2.setVisible(true);
}); 
btnNewButton.setBounds(238, 131, 178, 84); 
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

Еще один вариант - использовать `CardLayout`
Только теперь вам надо добавлять все компоненты не на `jframe1` и `jframe2`, а на `panel` и `panel2`

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(0, 0);
        contentPane.setLayout(cardLayout);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, "panel1");
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Open 2");
        panel.add(button2);
        
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Here JPanel №1");
        panel.add(l1);
        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel2, "panel2");
        
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Here JPanel №2");
        panel2.add(l2);
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Open 1");
        panel2.add(button1);
        
        button1.addActionListener(e -> {
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, "panel1");
        });
        button2.addActionListener(e -> {
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, "panel2");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Хм), немного не понял, где тут переход по кнопке в другой класс)

Comment: Ну у тебя же у нужного класса `extends JFrame`?

Comment: да, это так, верно.

Comment: Правил ответ, что бы стало понятнее

Comment: JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("JFRAME2");
  btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Acrom", Font.PLAIN, 22));
  btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                           frame2.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
  btnNewButton.setBounds(238, 131, 178, 84);
  frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

Comment: Снова правил ответ

Comment: а где объявляется frame2?

Comment: Можете объявить над `JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("JFRAME2");`

Comment: "а где объявляется frame2?" -- вообще говоря, это вопрос к тебе). В вопросе ты указал, что у тебя есть 2 JFrame -- текущий и "другой". Другой -- и есть frame2. Собственно, реакция на нажатие прописана в листенере

Comment: @Legend Developer - Добавил вариант с использованием `CardLayout`, думаю он вам понравиться больше, чем переключение между JFrame-ами

Answer (score 0):

Решил всё таки использовать JFrame метод, т.к. мне нужен будет дизайнер, проблема лишь только с объявлением второго JFrame

[image: stack]

Comment: Я в свой ответ добавил вариант с использованием `CardLayout`, думаю он вам понравиться больше, чем переключение между JFrame-ами, т.к это решит вашу проблему с "объявлением' и сделает переход плавным